# I need most complicated query

Tags: linq

I use Linq to Sql.
I have three table.

1. tabl_Region: from this table returning .ToList() via county column == 85
2. tabl_Season: from this table returning .ToList() via startdate >= today
3. tabl_Desc: from this table returning int [] ID via fldRegion== 1 results && fldSeason== 2 results

I will try to explain not worked codes

```
TurkusEntities context = new TurkusEntities();
return  context.tabl_AttrDesc.Where(c => c.fldRegionId == context.tabl_Region.Where(r => r.fldCounty == 85).ToList() && c.fldSeasonId == context.tabl_Season.Where(s => s.fldStartDate >= DateTime.Now).ToList()).ToList;
```

I know i can solve it by using loops, but if it is possible i want to use only query.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linq2Sql you can get the
[sql that is generated by a linq query.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Linq_DataContext_GetCommand_System_Linq_IQueryable_) with this command.

```
dc.GetCommand(query).CommandText
```

If you are using SQL Server Profiler inside the Sql Server (Tools --> SQL Server Profiler)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need more complicated. It is impossible on one query i solve it some process.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution but not impossible in one query.
First I got int [] ID arrays which match conditions from two tables.After I wrote a query which provide control column data from arrays.

```
 TurkusEntities context = new TurkusEntities();
 Region region = new Region();
 string[] dataarray = region.GetAllRegionsBySomeRule(RegionX); 
 var _db= context.tabl_AttrDesc.Where(c =>dataarray.Contains(c.fldRegionId.ToString().Trim())).ToList();
```

And Region

```
 public string[] GetAllRegionsBySomeRule(int fldType,int fldRegionX)
 {
 TurkusEntities context = new TurkusEntities();
 var _db = context.tabl_Region.Where(c => c.fldTown.Contains(fldRegionX.ToString())).ToList();
 foreach (var data in _db)
 {
 Regions.Add(data.fldId.ToString().Trim());
 }
 string[] IDS = Regions.ToArray();
 return IDS;           
 }
```